# indentation different on different computers

Tags: indentation, filetype-sh

If I indent the following script with `gg=G`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
    case "${1}" in
        -h) usage; exit 0;;
        -b) branch="${2}"; shift 2;;
        -t) build="${2}"; shift 2;;
        -w) write=true; shift 1;;
        --) shift; break;;
    esac
done
```

it gets differently indented on two different machines. On machine 1, the indentation is as above, on machine 2, all the different cases (starting from `-b`) gets indented to the left. Both machines have exactly the same `.vimrc`, where I use `aindent` only. On machine 1, vim is version 8.0, on machine 2, it's 7.4. Surely the version should not have such an effect? What else could lead to a different indentation?

Here are a few settings that I use on machine 1:

```
filetype detection:ON plugin:ON indent:ON
  softtabstop=0                                                                               
  tabstop=4                                                                                   
        Last set from ~/.vimrc                                                                
  shiftwidth=4                                                                                
        Last set from ~/.vimrc                                                                
nocindent                                                                                     
  indentexpr=                                                                                 
  autoindent                                                                                  
        Last set from ~/.vimrc                                                                
nosmartindent
```

And indeed there is one difference on machine 2:

```
  indentexpr=GetShIndent()
    Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/sh.vim
```

Removing it does not improve the situation, though. So after all, it might be due to a difference in the version of vim. Is there a good setting of indenting that works for both versions?

Comment: Check the output of `:filetype`. Also, Vim 8 comes with better indent script for shell scripts. Also interesting to know: `:verbose set sts? ts? sw? cindent? indentexpr? autoindent? smartindent?`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Edited my question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can probably use the indent script from machine 2 for machine 1 as well. Is the indent script not working correctly?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt But the problem is on machine 2, so changing the settings on machine 1 does not seem to be the way to go.

Comment: well, then do not set indentexpr on machine2. Also you did not show the output of `:filetype` for both systems. I suppose, that one includes `indent: ON` while the other does not. So that `:filetype` correctly should fix it for you. BTW, if the indent script does not work correctly for the case statement above, you might want to create a new issue on https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-sh-indent

Comment: If I do `set indentexpr=` on machine 2, then the indenting is still broken, though in a different way. I've shown the output of `:filetype`, it's the same on both machines.